# Codeigniter access variable data which is defined on function1 on function2

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, scope

I have two functions in a class. What i need is something like this (**This is incorrect**)

```
class Home{

    function one(){
        $var1 = "abc";
    }

    function two(){
        $var2 = $var1;
        echo $var2; //This needs to output 'abc' for me.
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not working.
Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: Yes I understand the scopes, but is there a anyway i can access that variable defined in another function?

Comment: "*Yes I understand the scopes*" Obviously not.

Comment: I would suggest you also read up on [class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, one of the ways is mentioned below, if you're learning OOP then I'd suggest watching [mmtuts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Anz0ArcQ5kI) videos which are quite informative.

```
<?php 

class Home{

    public $var1 = 'xyz';

    function one($x){ // or public function ... 

        $this->var1 = $x;
    }

    function two(){ // or public function ...

        $var2 = $this->var1;
        echo "var2: {$var2}"; //This needs to output 'abc' for me.
    }

}

$xyz = new Home(); // instantiate the class
$xyz->one('abc'); // call the function, pass the variable 
$xyz->two();    // get the value
```